# wordpress-how to remove the word [contact-form-7 404 "Not Found"]

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, contact-form-7

I already remove the contact form and the error came out.I don't want to use the contact form. How am I going to remove the words on the image?

> contact-form-7 404 "Not Found"

[image]

Comment: We need to see code

Comment: Try to check plugin is it installed or not ? Make it active

Comment: may be its included somewhere in the template file? you can try to search and remove where the file is used.

Comment: i am newbie with wordpress.so i dont know where are the page file located

Answer (score 0):

Go to template file and remove the line which you used to display contact form 7 that is delete the line

echo do_shortcode([contact-form-7 'your form name']);

Or if that is displaying from editor just delete the line

[contact-form-7 'your form name']

from your page's editor.

You have removed the contact form but code still exist.